# Intel Linux graphic drivers to HP 250 G5 laptop issue

Tags: drivers, graphics, ppa

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.1 LTS into an HP 250 G5 laptop with this characteristics:

- Intel Pentium N3710 @ 1,6 GHZ;
- 8GB RAM;
- 81F1 Motherboard;
- Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 405 (Braswell);
- ATA Toshiba MQ01ABD1 1 TB Internal HDD.

My issue is about I downloaded the oibaf/graphics-drivers packages, with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

Even the fact that all is working so fine, and the packages are upgraded almost every day. I don't feel these packages had done something to improve the graphical performance of this computer.

So, I tried to uninstall it with this commands:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

But I got an error message about the order "ppa-purge" was not to be found!

If I write:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

Then I get the error message: `Package ppa:oibaf not founded`

So, what's wrong here?

How can I full uninstall these packages and get back to the "original" system drivers?

Comment: Errors messages are right. `ppa-purge` is not installed by default and there is no package like `ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`. Using the second command you seem to have installed at least ppa-purge package. Now the first command should work. Adding a ppa doesn't mean installing a package. By adding the ppa you added the **sources** of the package. If you want to purge ppa, you also use `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`. Also, you haven't clarified if you have installed any package using that ppa, so I can't comment on uninstallation of packages.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about ppa-purge is not installed by default. BTW, I installed it and run it, but... The oibaf graphic packages are still installed here (ppa-purge didn't uninstall it). So...

Comment: What was the name of the package you installed using that ppa? Your question is unclear unless you specify the package name or at least the guide you are following.

Comment: I found the reason ppa-purge didn't work! There was an error with another ppa address which gaves an error from repository list. I fixed that and now I get the original drivers! Thank you so much! How can I mark this as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I installed "ppa-purge" (which is not installed by default) and I run it. So... I could uninstall the unwanted ṕackages and re-install the original system graphic drivers (ppa-purge does the whole job).